# can tern eclipse validate javascript in html files?

Tags: eclipse, tern

I am trying to use Tern Eclipse IDE in a static web project. Alas, I'm not able to configure it to validate javascript in script tags in .html files. Is this even supported? Is there any doc how to do it?

Comment: Please share your project and create an issue at tern.java